# Calculating third sunday of a month

Tags: php

I use this code to determine which month we're in:

```
$monthyear = date('F Y');
```

and then this to determine the third Sunday of a month

```
$thirdsunday = date("D, j M Y", strtotime($monthyear . ' third sunday'));
```

The outcome is Sun, 22 Mar 2015, which happens to be the 4th Sunday of the month (Sun 1 March, 8 March, 15 March)..

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

It should be the *third sunday of March 2015*

```
$thirdsunday = date("D, j M Y", strtotime('third sunday of ' . $monthyear));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: If you want to take a more OO approach, PHP has the DateTime class too, e.g. `$d = new DateTime('third sunday of ' . $monthyear);`. Depending on your code, this may be a more appropriate style. It's especially handy + readable if you're going to put that date in many places, but formatted differently, e.g.: `<div id="ticket"><?= $d->format('D, j M Y') ?></div>` then elsewhere `<p>The <?= $d->format('F dS') ?> show will be lots of fun!</p>`., which would make a ticket that says "Sun 15 Mar 2015", but more human-text that says "The March 15th show will be lots of fun!"

Answer (score 1):

> "ordinal dayname" does advance to another day. (Example "first wednesday july 23rd, 2008" means "2008-07-30").

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

This means that, when you say `third sunday` without the `of`, rather than doing "the third sunday of the month", it does, the third sunday *after* the given date; when you specify only a month, the *given date* is interpreted to be the first of the month, so the 3rd sunday *after* the first--when the first is a sunday-- would thus be the *fourth sunday* of the month.